# Odd Oracle Error

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm having a small issue with an Oracle command, given below:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT ID, NAME, RATING, LENGTH, STARTTIME FROM SCHEDULE WHERE ID=301 AND ROWNUM=1 AND SCHEDULE.STARTTIME <= SYSDATE ORDER BY STARTTIME DESC;";
```

It runs perfectly well in Oracle SQL Developer, returning exactly what I need, but in C#, i get the following error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 186:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:

. ( * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
like4 likec as between || indicator multiset member
submultiset
```

Can anyone see any issues with it, or anything that is illegal within C#?

EDIT: Execution code:

```
command.Connection = conSQL;
using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    do
    {
        int count = reader.FieldCount;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                 string setting = reader.GetName(i).ToString();
                 object value = reader.GetValue(i);

                 ** Data assigned to variables here, hidden due to length of code**
                 ** Follows pattern: object.property(reader.name) = reader.value **
            }

        }
    } while (reader.NextResult());
 }
```

Comment: could you post full error? following:.....?

Comment: There has to be something going weird with the execution code. Please post the rest of the error **and** the entire snippet of code that's executing the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dot not put ; at the end of the command, that's a command line tool convention, not part of sql proper (sqlplus also uses / as terminator for instance)

Comment: And that would cause it to say it encountered a `,` when parsing the statement?

Comment: @Mike: Oracle's error messages are known to be less than helpful.  First thing I thought was "There's probably a trailing semi-colon on the statement" and, yep, there it was.

Comment: @BobJarvis, awesome. And now that the OP posted the rest of the error I have to be honest, my heart sunk seeing that, it hold literally no value.

Comment: @Mike: it's all about trying things and seeing what happens.  I still have to believe that the ';' shouldn't be there - perhaps next to try is Skulmuk's idea of quoting the ID and NAME...

Comment: SQL is hard to parse, the syntax was defined at the height of the "natural language" fad, as a consequence locating errors is hard for the parser (Oracle is also notorious for the low quality of the error messages).

Comment: For whatever reason, it's working now. Nothing's changed, I've just re-removed the trailing ";" and it's fired off correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Name and Id are both special keywords in Oracle SQL.  Try:

```
SELECT "ID", "NAME"...
```

Comment: I've tried this, and combined with Bob's advice, get `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Comment: Add the ";" back to the statement and make sure that the capitilisation of your columns matches the definition as "ID" is case sensitive.

Comment: This could perhaps have been a problem, but `ID` and `NAME` are [**not reserved words** in Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm) (thankfully, since a good portion of database tables have an `ID` column :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the trailing semi-colon on the SQL statement.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: And that would cause it to say it encountered a `,` when parsing the statement?

Comment: If I remove the trailing semi-colon, I get `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

Comment: @Mike: As I noted below, Oracle's messages are often unhelpful in diagnosing the actual problem.  In this case the semi-colon at the end of the statement is the likely culprit.